# Lodash delay function doesn't let me to see state inside called function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash, use-effect, use-state

I am using lodash's delay function to call my function 3 times after certain time period and for some reason I can't see an updated React state in that function.
What can be a reason for that?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Delays from './helper';
import { delay } from 'lodash';

const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  console.log(progress); // Here I can see the updated state

  const testFunction = () => {
    console.log('inside function', progress); // here I can't see the updated state
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const seconds = 40;
    const attempts = 3;
    const milliseconds = 4000;

    setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 100 : prevProgress + 1
      );
    }, seconds * attempts * 10); // 1200

    for (let i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
      delay(testFunction, milliseconds * (i + 1));
    }
  }, []);
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
};

export default App;
```

The weird thing for me is that if I use a class based approach then I don't have any issues and the value of state will be present in my function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Delays from './helper';
import { delay } from 'lodash';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    progress: 0,
  };

  udpateProgress = (value) => {
    this.setState({ progress: value });
  };

  testFunction = () => {
    console.log('inside function', this.state.progress); // here I can see the Updated state
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const seconds = 40;
    const milliseconds = 4000;
    const attempts = 3;

    setInterval(() => {
      this.udpateProgress(
        this.state.progress >= 100 ? 100 : this.state.progress + 1
      );
    }, seconds * attempts * 10); // 1200

    for (let i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
      delay(this.testFunction.bind(this), milliseconds * (i + 1));
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log('inside render', this.state.progress);
    return <div>Hello World</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you've closed over the initial `progress` state value in `testFunction` that you are looping over from the `useEffect` that runs once on component mount.

## A Solution

A solution could be to use a React ref to hold the current state value that you can then reference in `testFunction`.

```
function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const progressRef = useRef(); // <-- ref to hold state value

  const testFunction = () => {
    console.log('inside function', progressRef.current); // <-- reference state value
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(progress); // <-- log per update
    progressRef.current = progress; // <-- cache state value
  }, [progress])

  useEffect(() => {
    const seconds = 40;
    const attempts = 3;
    const milliseconds = 4000;

    const timer = setInterval(() => { // <-- don't forget to save ref to interval timer
      setProgress((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 100 : prevProgress + 1
      );
    }, seconds * attempts * 10); // 1200

    for (let i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
      delay(testFunction, milliseconds * (i + 1));
    }

    return () => clearInterval(timer); // <-- to clear when component unmounts!!!
  }, []);
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit lodash-delay-function-doesnt-let-me-to-see-state-inside-called-function]

Comment: That is an excellent solution. May I please ask your opinion, why I didn't have the same problem in class based approach?

Comment: @Sonny49 Basically because class components don't have the same issue with Javascript enclosures that function components do (*because they are functions*). `this.state.progress` will always be a reference to the current state value. In this way, class components are more like objects have have an instance whereas function components are functions and are instanceless, they are "recreated" each render, and only hold on to references, such as the state and function I mentioned from the initial render cycle.